# How to decrease a field value every other day in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

One method would be to use cron job. https://github.com/javan/whenever.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I think using some form of scheduler (such as the whenever gem) along with a rake task is going to be your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider `cron` to be "one way" to do this then yes, there are countless "other ways".  This is because all of these ways would essentially be doing the same thing... Scheduling a task to run at periodic intervals.

Don't think of `cron` or any other scheduling tool as part of the application.  Separate the concerns of "performing the task" from the concerns of "scheduling the task."  Once you have an application which performs the task (and if the task in this case is just incrementing some persisted value then the entire application is going to be quite small) then separately you would use a scheduling system to schedule the task.

`cron` can do this.  So can countless others.  You could even write your own scheduler to run as a daemon or background service of some kind (the terminology depends on the platform, and platform differences regarding schedulers is a key reason to keep the concerns separated).

Comment: Why would you consider them separate (your cron and your application)? Without the cron, your business rules may not be met. You can't have a working deployment without it.

Comment: @ashes999: Because performing logic and scheduling logic are two distinct concerns.  For starters, if you tightly couple the application with a specific scheduler implementation then you can't invoke the application logic without that scheduler.  This makes the business logic more rigid and less portable, as well as less testable.  `cron`, or any scheduler, is an implementation detail.  It's not part of the business rules.  The *definition* of the scheduled tasks may be business rules ("every other day" for example), but the *implementation* of those rules is separate from that.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use any background workers familar with ruby on rails.
For example [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) and [rescue](https://github.com/resque/resque). Both have plugins for working with periodical tasks

sidekiq: [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) - Great choice. It has perfect interface integrated in standard sidekiq monitoring tool. I use it on all my projects.

resque: [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) - I used this scheduler couple years ago. All I know about it, it does its work well.